# How to get IBOutlet for NSColorPanel opened by a NSToolbarItem

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, iboutlet, nstoolbar, nscolorpanel

I have a NSToolbar. One of the default items (created by IB, so you can check it out by just adding an NSToolbar to a XIB) is an a NSToolbar item that opens NSColorPanel when clicked. However, I see no way to get a IBOutlet connecting the NSColorPanel to my code- which I need so I can get the NSColor. Obviously I'm missing something. Anybody know how to wire this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Yay me! What you need to do is implement `-(void)changeColor:` in the First Responder. Inside, just type `[sender color]` to get the color!